# Pandas check if list has consecutive numbers, return ["min-max"]

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a list column in a pandas dataframe. Here are some possible values:

```
|                   field1                      |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| ['01', '02', '03', '04', 'Other']             |
| ['-01', '00', '01', '06', '07', '08', '09']   |
| ['01', '06', '07', '08', '09']                |
| []                                            |
```

How can I replace these values so that whenever there are consecutive numbers, the min and max get concatenated with a '-', otherwise just keep the number:

```
|      field1         |
|---------------------|
| ['01-04', 'Other']  |
| ['-01-01', '06-09'] |
| ['01', '06-09']     |
| []                  |
```

Comment: Are these all stored as comma delimited strings!?

Comment: I'll make the assumption that since it says "list column" it's a list of strings missing the quotes.

Comment: Sorry about that! It kept giving me an error when trying to save the markdown table. The strings in the lists have quotes. I've updated the input and expected output

Answer (score 2):

You can try :

```
tmp = (
    df["field1"].explode().to_frame()
        .assign(idx= lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
        .set_index("idx", append=True)
)

nums = pd.to_numeric(tmp["field1"], errors="coerce")
groups = tmp.groupby(nums.diff().ne(1).cumsum())

func = lambda x: f"{min(x)}-{max(x)}" if min(x) != max(x) else x

out = (
    groups.apply(lambda g: g.fillna("").groupby(level=0).agg(func))
          .groupby(level=1).agg(list)
)

#​df["field1"] = out #uncomment this line to overwrite the original column
```

Output :

```
print(out)
​
            field1
0   [01-04, Other]
1  [-01-01, 06-09]
2      [01, 06-09]
3               []
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works for a list of strings. Other values might break it:**

```
def hyphenate_consecutive_numbers(lst):
    result = []
    start = None
    end = None

    for i, num_str in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            num = int(num_str)
            if start is None:
                start = num
                end = num
            elif num == end + 1:
                end = num
            else:
                result.append(f"{str(start)}-{str(end)}")
                start = num
                end = num
        except ValueError:
            if start is not None:
                result.append(f"{str(start)}-{str(end)}")
                start = None
                end = None
            result.append(num_str)

    if start is not None:
        result.append(f"{str(start)}-{str(end)}")

    return result


# Example usage:
lst = ["01", "02", "03", "Other", "04", "05", "06"]
result = hyphenate_consecutive_numbers(lst)
print(result)  # ['1-3', 'Other', '4-6']
```